# What is the correct way to enable PHP extentions, manually or via mods-available?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I am used to enabling PHP extensions by manually adding them into my `php.ini` file, for example: `extension=x.so`. But today I learned that one PHP extension failed to load because putting the `extension=x.so` fails because some extensions are loaded after the php.ini is contacted.

The solution I found was to use phpenmod and create a extension.ini file within `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available`. This solved my problem but my question is which is the correct way? - I was always used to manually editing my php.ini file, is that not recommended anymore, I can't seem to find much information on this? When did this change come about?

Comment: the Offical way, is the second.

Comment: @djdomi Can you link to any docs for this?

Comment: its the similar reason for nginx and also Apache - its the file structure of the Directories - you can see that also with `php-config` where it has been forced to used by your Distribution

Comment: @djdomi This is the Debian way, not the official way. The official way, such as it is, is to manaully edit the php.ini yourself, which is why Debian maintainers created this much easier scheme. It should be used when on Debian-based systems.

Comment: I am sorry, forgot about that ;) Using debian for now since 20+ years xD